# combine a console application with a GUI in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, parameter-passing, jtextarea

I want to combine a console application with a GUI in netbeans.I tried to do it using a jButton. I want to get the output of the console application into a jTextArea.

There is a function called `private static void printBytes(byte[] data, String name)` in the console application. When calling that function have to do as follow.

```
printBytes(activeKey,"After permuted choice 1 table- Active key:");
```

For this I have to pass the 2nd parameter to the text box. I created an object of the `jTextArea` called `ta` and gave

```
printBytes(activeKey,ta.append("After permuted choice 1 table- Active key:"));
```

It gave an error called

> Cannot convert void type into string.

Then I tried as follow.

```
String a="After permuted choice 1 table- Active key:"
printBytes(activeKey,ta.getText(a));
```

It also didn't work.
Someone please tell me how to do it.What i want to do is somehow connect my console application to GUI and getting the output on the GUI.

Comment: You're not trying to get the return of the printBytes(...) method into a String variable right?

Comment: Create a real GUI from scratch. Sure use a non-GUI model that's a true OOP class, but don't try to shoe-horn a console app into a GUI, especially one that displays its output via println.

Answer (score 2):

`Cannot convert void type into string.` tells you exactly what is wrong. The method you're calling, JTextArea#append(...) doesn't return a String but rather appends text to its display, and returns nothing, void, so you can't pass the method's result (there is none) into your printBytes method which expects a String.

You can "connect" a console app to a GUI by re-directing the standard output into the JTextArea, but again rather than trying to connect a console to a GUI, you're likely better to create a GUI app that is GUI from the get-go with a non-GUI model that holds its logic and is written so that it can be used in most any UI you choose, console, GUI or other (if it exists).